# Newman Docker cannot find env file

Tags: docker, postman, newman

Currently at the Automation stage of my pipeline, I'm seeing the follwing error:

> newman run collections/something.postman_collection.json -k
>
> error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
> 'collections/something.postman_collection.json'

Code from pipeline

Code:

> stage('Automation') {
>
> ```
> node('build') {
>
> def collectionName = 'collections/something.postman_collection.json'
>
> def postmanEnvName ='collections/somethingapi.postman_environment.json'
>
> def globalsname = 'collections/somethingglobals.postman_globals.json'
>
> docker.image('postman/newman_alpine33').inside("--entrypoint=''"){
>    sh "newman run $collectionName -k" 
> } } }
> ```

Any ideas on what might be the issue, i've tried a few different combos
e.g

"newman run $collectionName"

"newman $collectionName"

"newman /collections:/etc/newman run $collectionName"

docker.image('postman/newman_alpine33').inside("--entrypoint=''  -v /collections:/etc/newman")

Thanks!

Comment: How is `collections/something.postman_collection.json` provided? Is the file built into the docker image?

Comment: It is part of the build and being pulled into the jenkins workspace

Answer (score 0):

I think your build server doesn't have file or folder you trying to access. You probably already know `-v /collections:/etc/newman` mounts a host folder `/collections` on to your docker image at location `:/etc/newman`.

In your case, I am pretty sure there is folder at root by name `collections`, check where you are copying your collections file. You can also run and test your collection using npm module `newman`. In fact, this is what happens when you run through docker image. For ref here is [Dockerfile](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/blob/develop/docker/images/alpine33/Dockerfile).

Comment: Got it sorted, turns out it needed a

(`sh "cd ../"`)
in the block before the 
(`sh "newman run $collectionName -k" `)

So I guess the entrypoint was just a dir up from where I need it to be